# Select rows from pandas df, where index appears somewhere in another df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Assume the following:

df1:

```
x    y     z
1    10    11
2    20    22
3    30    33
4    40    44
1    20    21
1    30    31
1    40    41
2    10    12
2    30    32
2    40    42
3    10    31
3    20    23
3    40    43
4    10    14
4    20    24
4    30    34
```

df2:

```
x    b
1    100
2    200
```

df3:

```
y    c
10   1000
20   2000
```

I want all rows from `df1`, for which either `x` or `y` appears in either `df2` or `df3` respectively, meaning in this case

out:

```
x    y     z
1    10    11
2    20    22
1    20    21
1    30    31
1    40    41
2    10    12
2    30    32
2    40    42
3    10    31
3    20    23
4    10    14
4    20    24
```

I would like to do this in pure pandas, with no for loops, seems standard enough to me, but I don't really know what to look for

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) on both cases, chain the conditions with a `bitwise OR` and perform `boolean indexation` on the dataframe with the result:

```
df1[df1.x.isin(df2.x) | df1.y.isin(df3.y)]
```